# xpages Custom Control "fileDownload" don't display "modified file" in reader mode

Tags: xpages

I am using a "document library" (template: StdXLWebXDocLib). When I modify the Custom Control "fileDownload" and I put the `<displayLastModified option = "true">`, the modification date does not appear in Reader mode while it is displayed when i am in Edit mode.

Is this a XPAGES bug ? Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different fileDownload control on that page, inside different facets of a dynamic content container. You should modify both.