# XPages: file download control shows wrong created and modified date

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

### The XPages file download control shows wrong created and modified date

I have an XPages application running on a `Domino 8.5.3 FP6` Server and I have to deal with the following known bugs:

[LO68445: XPAGE: IN FILE DOWNLOAD CONTROL, CREATED COLUMN SHOWS DOCUMENT CREATED DATE, MODIFIED COLUMN SHOWS DOCUMENT MODIFIED DATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO68445)

[LO61249: CUSTOMER | THE FILE DOWNLOAD CONTROL DOESN'T DISPLAY THE DATE ST AMP OF THE FILE ATTACHED](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO61249)

---

Take a look at the following screenshots:

*First Step: Upload attachment ("added on" date is correct, because upload was done after the document creation)...*

[image]

*Second Step: Reopen the same document (as you can see the "added on" date is the same as the creation date of the document and that's wrong)...*

[image]

---

Thanks in advance for any solution, workaround or alternative!

Comment: I believe this is a known issue that is yet to be resolved. The IBM reference is [LO61249](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO61249) and you can find others out there, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182121/xpages-custom-control-filedownload-dont-display-modified-file-in-reader-mod), who have run in to the same issue. I believe your best solution is as you identified in your answer, to override the attribute and compute it yourself.

Comment: @EricMcCormick: Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLUTION (WORKAROUND):

After some investigations, I have found a possible workaround. The only thing you have to do is to override the `createdValue` attribute of the `xp:fileDownload` control:

```
<xp:fileDownload id="fileDownload" indexVar="fileIndex" var="fileData" 
    hideWhen="false" value="#{currentDocument.Body}" sizeTitle="Size" 
    fileNameTitle="Filename" createdTitle="Added on">
    <xp:this.createdValue><![CDATA[#{javascript: //workaround
    if (fileIndex == 0 && @Attachments() <= 1) return @AttachmentModifiedTimes();
    else return @AttachmentModifiedTimes()[fileIndex];}]]></xp:this.createdValue>
</xp:fileDownload>
```

**Any further solutions, workarounds are welcome!**